# Deactivate maven-ear-plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-ear-plugin

The goal `ear:ear` is automatically attached to the package phase if one builds an ear. I would like to eliminate it. Unfortunately, it has no `skip` parameter.

How can I "deattach" a goal from a phase?

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something, but what's the point of packaging an EAR without generating an EAR?

Comment: @RafaelOdon The ear is produced by different means (by downloading a given ear and manipulating it).

Comment: Why don't you just perform a `compile` instead of `package`?

Comment: I want to install and deploy the ear, I just want to build it "myself" instead of using the maven-ear-plugin, i.e. using self-written code.

Comment: First why are you trying to do something which already exist? What exactly is the reason for doing so? What kind of issues/problems do you have?

Comment: The requirement is to download an ear from nexus, create an additional properties file, add it to the ear and upload that ear (under a different name) to nexus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After I found out the execution id (default-ear), I successfully did the following:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-ear</id>
        <phase>none</phase>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```